# System freezes during Bash auto-completion with Tab or Ctrl+R

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, auto-completion

It started about a week ago, don't know why. Now, when I type something like `cd somedir` and click <kbd>Tab</kbd>, my system completely freezes for about 10 seconds. I can move the cursor but can't switch between windows or terminal tabs. After 10 seconds, everything gets back to normal. Exactly the same thing happens with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Even when I'm on a remote host (using `ssh`), the system freezes, when I try to auto-complete the directories or files using <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This all is really annoying.

What's that and how to fix it?

Ubuntu 14.04, x64. Standard distrib. Haven't changed `$PATH` as far as I remember. Anyway, `echo $PATH` shows this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: What specs does the system have, with which version of Ubuntu? It may be a disk issue as CtrlR and Tab autocompletion need to search through a large amount of stuff on disk to find matches.

Comment: Do you have unreachable or disconnected nfs mountpoints? I had the same symptoms as you describe and that was the cause in my case.

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: what do the logs say?